# Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) keeps forgetting DPI scaling setting

Tags: unity, scaling, dpi, hdpi

Unity interface scaling resets back to 1.0 on every display reconnection. It worked fine in the past. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution, @Roman?

Comment: Unfortunately i did not.

Answer (score 4):

The bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1689356). It affects 17.04 and 16.04. No solution yet, but someone has released a patch [here](https://launchpad.net/~arter97/+archive/ubuntu/unity), which worked for me.